# Conflict between Network Manager and Player Input Manager

Tags: networking, input

When creating a networked game with netcode along with using Unitys Player Input Manager for input there appears to be a conflict between the spawning of the player prefab. Both the network manager and player input manager require spawning of a player prefab so that it has a reference to it but of course, it spawns in two at a time. So if only one needs to do the spawning then which is better to handle it, the network manager or the player input manager and if so which one is easiest to send data to in terms of player data and control inputs?